# How to programmatically launch into another viewController if your user is logged in through Facebook

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, uiviewcontroller, swift3

Basically I have one class called facebookLogin.swift, the login page, and ViewController.Swift the homepage. I have correctly coded all the Facebook login stuff and it all works, I can log in and log out with both the button the FBSDK provides as well as the custom button I have defined. However, I can not figure out how to go to the ViewController.swift page if the user is logged in.

Here is the facebookLogin.swift code:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class facebookLogin: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
    var loginStatus = false;

    @IBOutlet weak var facebookOutlet: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let loginButton  = FBSDKLoginButton()
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        loginButton.center = view.center
        loginButton.delegate = self;
        loginButton.readPermissions = ["email","public_profile"]
    }

    @IBAction func facebookAction(_ sender: Any) {
        customFBLogin()
        if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) {
            NSLog("it works")
        }
    }

    func customFBLogin() {
        FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email","public_profile"], from: self) { (result, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("Facebook Login Error Failed \(err)")
                return;
            }
            self.showEmailAddress();
            self.loginStatus = true;
        }
    }



    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("Did log out of Facebook")
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return;
        } else {
            print("Successfuly logged into Facebook");
            showEmailAddress()

        }
    }

    func showEmailAddress() {
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, err) in

            if err != nil {
                print("Failed to start graph request \(err)")
                return;
            }
            print(result)

        })
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Here is the relevant code from the AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FIRApp.configure()
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        var initialViewController: UIViewController

        if(FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) {
            let vc = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
            initialViewController = vc
        } else{
            initialViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "facebookLogin")
        }

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        return handled;
    }
```

In the first application function in the AppDelegate.swift class, I have found another tutorial on stackoverflow which suggested using this code. I inputted the code and converted the syntax to swift3, but the app breaks when I launch it. This means that it knows that I am logged in but for some reason the segue does not load and it breaks the app. The error I get is Thread 1: sigabrt.

Here is how the relevant items in the story board look, at first the initial view Controller is on the left and if the user is logged in I want the app to start from the viewController on the right
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EEL5.png)

Comment: have you defined storyboard id's ?

Comment: are you using real device?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok. You should consider checking Storyboard ID of your ViewController under Identity section in Storyboard design screen. You should give Storyboard ID as "ViewController". Login screen's Storyboard ID should be "facebookLogin" according to your code.

Comment: Could you try the code below behind your button process after successfully logged in?


`    let vc =     self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! UIViewController;
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 code

> // Check Last AccesToken

```
    if let accessToken = AccessToken.current {
        print("Last AccesToken -\(accessToken)")

        // Redirect to next screen
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"NextScreen", sender: self)
    }
    else {

        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.loginBehavior = LoginBehavior.web
        loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile , .email, .userFriends], viewController: self) { loginResult in
            switch loginResult {

            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
                break
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login.")
                break
            case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                print("Logged in! \(grantedPermissions) \(accessToken) \(declinedPermissions)")

                // Save Current UserInfo
                let params = ["fields":"id,name,email,picture"]
                let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
                graphRequest.start { (urlResponse, requestResult) in
                    switch requestResult {
                    case .failed(let error):
                        print(error)
                    case .success(let graphResponse):
                        if let responseDictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {

                            print("\(String(describing: graphResponse.dictionaryValue))")

                            UserDefaults.standard.set(responseDictionary, forKey: "userInfo")
                        }
                    }
                }

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NextScreen", sender: self)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```